# Using custom counters in Hadoop to keep the Map-Recuce job alive?

Tags: hadoop, solr, lucene, mapreduce

I am using  a mapper only job to generate indexes for Solr. In my mapper code,using Lucene API's `org.apache.lucene.index.IndexWriter` and add `org.apache.lucene.document.Document` to the `IndexWriter`.
In the `close()` method, I am using `writer.forceMerge(1)` to consolidate the indexes and finally close the `IndexWriter` using `writer.close()` to commit the indexes to Local FileSystem  before closing. However, some of the tasks fail as the committing process sometimes takes a long time ( > 600 seconds). This often leads to the failure of the job.

The issue seems to be that the tasks are unable to inform TaskTracker about their progress during the execution of `close()/writer.close()` method call ultimately leads to TT killing the tasks.

In order to prevent this from happening, I am starting a thread in `close()` which increments a custom counter to notify the Job Tracker of the job progress; then I stop this thread as soon as the `writer.close()` call is complete

This temporary workaround seems to work for now. But would like to know if there are any better ways to solve this issue? Moving to Cloudera Search is not an option for now.

*Setup:

Solr Version : 4.1

Hadoop Version: CDH3u5*

Answer (score 0):

Simply, remove `writer.forceMerge(1)`.

This forces the writer to merge segments down to one single segment.  It's an *extremely costly* operation, even when you aren't merging to 1 segment, and you almost certainly don't need it!  Let the merge policy handle when to merge segments for you.

There are some other things you might do as well, to shorten the time for these operations, like keeping a writer open for use, instead of opening a new one every time.  Really, though, I think the `forceMerge` will be *by far* the largest part of the problem.

For more on why `optimize`/`forceMerge` are only hurting you: [Simon says: Optimize is bad for you](http://blog.trifork.com/2011/11/21/simon-says-optimize-is-bad-for-you/)

Comment: Your comments are totally valid.The indexes are being built from scratch as a part of batch job, so while building , it is important that we have the most **optimized** index even if it comes at the cost of an expensive operation. Removing `forceMerge(1)` call will only lead to increase in query time. The approach taken here is of divide-and-conquer - where in each mapper produces one and only one index segment ; which later are combined using a dedicated merge process. (Here it helps to have fewer segments thanks to `forceMerge()`)

Answer (score 0):

You can set the "mapred.task.timeout" property to a higher value.

By default this is 600000 milliseconds.